# Problem with an indent on donut icing?

Tags: particles

Following *Blender Gurus* tutorial, I have got a problem I need help with. I flipped the direction of the particles and set the offset to -1; it was not flipped properly and it now has a weird ringed indent in the middle. This is what I have so far.

[image]

I am just a beginner so far, so I don't know what the particle function is used for.

If you're not watching the video, it's for the icing.

[image]

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. :You already asked this here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82856/a-problem-with-the-donut-icing-random-indent-in-icing

Comment: I went through this problem and realized that in the previous build, I had not applied the scale - follow the link with the moment he comments on the future problems of not doing this. [This part of the tutorial.](https://youtu.be/imdYIdv8F4w?t=444)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the icing.
2. Press  <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go into *Edit Mode*.
3. Press  <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices/edges/faces.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd>  to recalculate the normals.
5. Press  <kbd>T</kbd> to to open the toolbar, then go to *Shading/UVs* and press *Flip Direction* under normals.
6. Press  <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to go out of *Edit Mode*.

Like Blender Guru states in his video: the particle system's behaviour is strange  because normally you assume that it works with recalculated normals but you need to flip the direction. That's also the reason why you had to change the offset of the Solidify modifier to -1.